# clang++ 3.2 with libstdc++-6.dll on Windows 7 (32 bit)

Tags: c++, windows, clang++

After searching alot at Stackoverflow and Googling out my problem, I still can't run an .EXE file build using clang++ 3.2.

"clang++" gives out no error when compiling .BC file into .EXE. The moment I try to run the .EXE file, it suddenly terminates the program.

[image: Error Message when I execute a program]

Can anyone help me with this?

I've already tried to use -static-libstdc++-6/libstdc++, but the problem remains.

**Side note**: executables made using g++ compile without any problem and run fine.

**EDITED**:

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a=0;
cin>>a;
cout<<a<<endl;
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Attach a debugger and debug it.

Comment: A debugger would certainly be a great place to start, especially since the one thing needed to assist with this (the ***code***) is not part of your question. Assuming that "using clang 3.2" means "*compiled with* clang 3.2".

Comment: is this the same even with an "int main() { return 0; }" c++ program? If not, could you please attach a short snippet? Also, you may want to consider 3.3 in the future.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I added my code :)

Comment: @LaszloPapp: The code gives no error when returning a zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use gcc version 4.7.0 or higher, try [Making Clang work with MinGW GCC 4.7's libstdc++](http://tehsausage.com/clang-mingw-gcc-4-7).