# Unknown error when compiling Clang 3.3 with Mingw

Tags: windows, mingw, clang

I'm not able to compile clang(3.3) using MinGW 4.8.1. The following error always pops-up when 70% build is complete:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `clang/lib/Basic/FileManager.cpp` includes `sys/stat.h`, which defines `#define stat _stat64i32` (actually there are a few other defines in between, but you get the idea ;)
2. `clang/include/clang/Basic/FileManager.h` does not include `sys/stat.h`; instead only has a forward-declaration.
3. Hence, while parsing the header, the forward declaration is used (`struct stat`)
4. But when it finally arrives at the implementation, the preprocessor will kick in and replace `struct stat` with `struct stat64i32`. Hence the mismatch.

The best solution would be to change the forward declaration in the header to instead include `sys/stat.h`. (I didn't actually test if it will compile then)

The current trunk does not contain the code anymore.

Update: regarding `off64_t`. This is defined in `_mingw_off_t.h` these days as:

```
#ifndef _OFF64_T_DEFINED                                                           
#define _OFF64_T_DEFINED                                                           
  __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef long long _off64_t;                                    
#if !defined(NO_OLDNAMES) || defined(_POSIX)                                                                                                                                                                
  __MINGW_EXTENSION typedef long long off64_t;                                     
#endif                                                                             
#endif /*_OFF64_T_DEFINED */
```

So you probably want to define `_POSIX` before including `io.h` (or `stdio.h`)

Comment: Thank you very much :) It worked! But now it's giving at error at 98% ..  http://tinypic.com/r/jp769c/5

Can you tell me how did you find this error?

Comment: I had to mess around with `sys/stat.h` on mingw in the past. After that it was pretty obvious and just a matter of looking for it in the right place. Please do not post error messages as images. Copy/paste that stuff.

Comment: I added this in io.h. It works :p . Hey! I also have another problem. I think you can help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541647/clang-3-2-with-libstdc-6-dll-on-windows-7-32-bit